# Bigquery: How to re-import the expired dataset from Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I recently upgraded from sandbox mode to the billing account to keep the data set without expiry.
As some data which linked with Firebase has been already expired, I would like to re-import all the data in Firebase Analytics.
Could anybody provide the guidance to get all the data linked with Firebase ?

I've already unlink the connection between Firebase and Bigquery and re-linked it again. But, it seems not to be working.

Comment: Are you referring to data in Firebase Analytics in particular?

Comment: Yes, we are using Firebase to measure the events users take on our mobile app.

Comment: Data is only exported when the integration is enabled. There is no way to export historical data from Firebase or Google Analytics to BigQuery.

Comment: Understood that linking historical data is not possible. Is there any way to export the historical data for the data analysis by using SQL? 

I asked the question on the separated thread so it would be appreciated if you could comment in case you know the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64110469/the-best-way-to-analyze-historical-data-on-firebase-by-using-sql